# Prove or disprove the inequality if $a,b,c>0$, $a \geq b+c$.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, geometric-inequalities

Prove or disprove the inequality
$$a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b \geq 7abc$$ if $$a,b,c>0, a \geq b+c.$$
I thought to use this evaluation:
$$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a \geq 3abc.$$
So we have:
$$a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b \geq 3abc+3abc=6abc,$$ which is obvious that $$6abc<7abc.$$
Is it right? I'm embarrassed that in my solution I did not have to use the condition that $$a \geq b+c.$$
Any hint would help a lot. thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the initial inequality say $\le 7abc$? Otherwise the trivial substitution of $a=b=c=1$ gives you $6 \ge 7$, which is false.

Comment: How do you conclude that every summand is at least $abc$ ? And even then, why should something $\ge6abc$ not be $7abc$  or larger ?

Comment: @DanielP if we use a=b=c=1, then the condition $$a \geq b+c$$ is wrong

Comment: Ah true. Well in that case, you do need to use the condition somewhere!

Comment: if you are wondering how one can systematically arrive at a solution, then get rid of the extra condition $a\geq b+c$ by substituting $a = b+c+d$, $d\geq 0$ and turn this into a n inequality of $b,c,d\geq 0$ with no extraneous constraint to deal with. 

Alternatively, your inequality is a quadratic in $a$ with a positive leading coefficient.  Since quadratic inequalities are completely solved by basic calculus, you can also be certain that it will lead you to a solution by checking all possible cases of the roots of the quadratic against $a\geq b+c.$

Answer (score 3):

Since $$b+c\geq\frac{7bc-b^2-c^2}{2(b+c)},$$ we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)-7abc=(b+c)a^2+(b^2+c^2-7bc)a+bc(b+c)\geq$$
$$\geq(b+c)^3+(b^2+c^2-7bc)(b+c)+bc(b+c)=2(b+c)(b-c)^2\geq0.$$

Answer (score 3):

Dividing by $abc > 0,$ the relation to be shown is $$  \frac{b+c}{a}  + \frac{c+a}{b} + \frac{a+b}{c} \overset?\ge 7$$

Set $a = b+c + d$  for $d \ge 0.$ We then need to argue that for $b,c>0, d\ge 0,$

$$ \frac{b+c}{b+c+d} + \frac{2c+d}{b} + \frac{2b+d}{c} \overset?\ge 5$$

The LHS is invariant under scaling, so wlog set $b = 1.$ We need to show that for $c > 0, d \ge 0,$ $$ J(c,d) := \frac{1 + c}{1 + c + d} + 2c + d + \frac{2 + d}{c} \overset?\ge 5.$$

For a fixed value of $c$, the derivative with respect to $d$ is $$ \partial_d J = 1 + \frac{1}{c} -\frac{(1+c)}{(1 + c + d)^2} \ge 1 + \frac{1}{c} - \frac{1}{1+c} > 0. $$ This means that for any fixed $c$, $J$ attains its minimum at $d = 0.$ So we need ot argue that $J(c,0) \ge 5$ for any $c> 0,$ i.e. that $$ 1 + 2c + \frac2c \overset?\ge 5 \iff c + \frac1c \overset?\ge 2.$$ But this holds via the AM-GM inequality. We conclude that the original inequality is true.